# Define assets precompile for every controller in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am familiar with Rails already but I downloaded a Rails demo App to see some best practices.

My question is about the asset pipeline which is still confusing to me. In my other Rails app I have one JS and one CSS file for every controller and I can write whatever I want in there and it works.

In my demo app I find those two lines:

```
<!-- =============== VIEW VENDOR STYLES ===============-->
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>

<!-- =============== VIEW VENDOR SCRIPTS ===============-->
   <%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %>
```

When I start my App I get an error and to solve this I have to add these two lines

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( xxx.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( xxx.js )
```

for every controller to my initializers/assets.rb file.

Is somehow annoying. What is this all about?

Comment: You can create a `manifest` file and require all the css there and precompile it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what "Demo App" you have downloaded... Anyway - it has probably the "require_tree" in application.js removed or disabled. That way your Javascripts are neither included nor precompiled. To restore the default behaviour you need to have the

```
//= require_tree .
```

present at the end of `application.js`. The same applies for (s)css assets. Only there the line looks like:

```
 *= require_tree .
```

at the end of the top comment block in `application.css.scss`

Please note that having those lines there in production environment makes all the files included and compiled into one large file, which is later used on every page of your application whether needed or not. There are ways around it but that's the default behaviour. Because the "Demo App" you refer to has it (most probably) disabled, it might have had some reasons behind disabling the `require_tree` line(s).